# Unable to convert object detection code using Detectron2 to .exe file

Tags: python, pytorch, pyinstaller, torch, cx-freeze

I have developed an object detection algorithm using Detectron2 and I want to convert it to a standalone executable file so that I can run it on a computer that doesn't have Python or Detectron2 installed.

I have tried using PyInstaller to create a .exe file, but when I run it, I get the error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\env01\lib\site-packages\pathspec-0.11.1-py3.9.egg\EGG-INFO\top_level.txt'". I believe this is because PyInstaller is not able to correctly package all the necessary Detectron2 files.

I have also tried using other methods such as cx_Freeze, but I have encountered similar issues.

Can anyone guide me on how to properly package Detectron2 and my code into a standalone executable file?

Thank you.

Comment: create a [mre].